# Protected Friend em Vb.Net: o campo também é visível em outros projetos

Tags: vb.net

Estou estudando Modificadores de acesso em Vb.net e me surgiu uma dúvida em Protected Friend

*Segundo o site* macoratti.net:

- **Protected:** esconde os membros de uma classe e "os membros marcados com o modificador Protected podem ser acessados na mesma classe e em todas as classes que herdam da classe."
- **Friend:** "você quer que todas as classes do seu projeto sejam capazes de acessar os membros da sua classe mas que classes externas ao seu projeto não tenham este direito.

Neste cenário nem o modificador `Private` nem o `Protected` podem lhe ajudar, para esta situação temos o modificador `Friend`.

Assim sendo, tenho dois projetos em uma mesma solução, `Proj1` e `Proj2`:

Em `Proj1`, tenho a classe Aluno:

```
Public Class Aluno

        Public Nome As String
        Protected Endereco As AlunoEndereco
        Protected Friend idade As Integer
        Protected Class AlunoEndereco
            Public Rua As String
            Public Cidade As String
            Public Estado As String
            Public Cep As String
        End Class
    End Class
```

e em `Proj2` tenho a classe Teste que herda de Aluno:

```
Class Teste
    Inherits Aluno

    Sub New()
        idade = 2
    End Sub
End Class
```

Como um modificador de acesso `Protected` permite um membro só ser visível na **própria classe e em classes herdadas**, mas ao combinar com o modificador `protected` com `friend`, pensei que aconteceria que o campo idade só pudesse ser visto dentro da classe em `Proj1` mas não em `Proj2`, mas aconteceu que também foi possível acessar idade a partir da classe Teste em `Proj2`, alguém poderia me explicar por que isto acontece?

Comment: Algum duvida ainda ficou vago...?

Comment: ok, tudo certo.

Answer (score 1):

No próprio site da Microsoft fala sobre o assunto:

> [Friend protegido (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/protected-friend)

*A combinação de palavras-chave Protected Friend é um modificador de acesso de membro. Ele confere ambos amigo acesso e protegido acesso os elementos declarados, portanto, eles são acessíveis de qualquer lugar no mesmo assembly, de sua própria classe e de classes derivadas. Você pode especificar Protected Friend somente em membros de classes; não é possível aplicar Protected Friend aos membros de uma estrutura porque as estruturas não podem ser herdadas.* ***Ref.*** [Friend protegido (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/protected-friend)

Quando só tem o [modificador de acesso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels) [Friend](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/friend) (*que é o mesmo em C# `internal`*) é visto dentro do mesmo projeto, mas, com a junção de `Protected` acaba abrindo o acesso as outros projetos internamente em suas classes com Herança ter visibilidade do membro.

***Exemplo:***

**Projeto 1**

```
Public Class Pasta1
    Friend P0 As String
    Protected Friend P1 As String
End Class
```

**Projeto 2**

```
Imports Prj1

Public Class Pasta2
    Inherits Pasta1
    Sub New()
        // 'Prj1.Pasta1.P0' is not accessible in 
        // this context because it is 'Friend'      
        Me.P0 = "abc"      

        Me.P1 = "abc" // Ok, está acessivel
     End Sub
End Class
```

Ou seja, essa é a diferença.

***Nota:*** [o contexto da declaração só em nível de classe, ou seja, somente classe, excluindo ai arquivo de origem, `namespace`,`interface`, estruturas, módulos e procedimentos.](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/protected-friend#rules)